# AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'

Tags: python, datetime

I have a function shown below, but keep getting an error. My input are shown below:

```
def get_start_and_end_pst_dates(date_min_utc, date_max_utc):
 
    date_min_pst=date_min_utc.tz_localize('UTC').astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
    date_max_pst=date_max_utc.tz_localize('UTC').astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
    
   
    day_start_str=str(date_min_pst)[:-6]
    day_end_str=str(date_max_pst)[:-6]

    day_end=datetime.strptime(day_end_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    day_start=datetime.strptime(day_start_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    query_datetime = day_end + timedelta(hours=1)
    query_date_end = query_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    query_datetime = day_start - timedelta(hours=1)
    query_date_start=query_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return query_date_start,query_date_end
```

input

```
datetime_str_start = '09/19/18 13:55:26'
datetime_str_end = '09/19/18 14:55:26'

datetime_object_start = datetime.strptime(datetime_str_start, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
datetime_object_end = datetime.strptime(datetime_str_end, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')


a,b = get_start_and_end_pst_dates(datetime_object_start,datetime_object_end)
```

Any help thank you!

Comment: `tz_localize` is a pandas datetime / Timestamp method, however you seem to be working with Python datetime. In general, use one or the other, but don't mix - to avoid exactly such errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it using:

```
import pytz

datetime_object_start = datetime.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).isoformat()
```

or to use your format;

```
datetime_object_start = datetime.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```